# Spring Security latest version securityFilterChain configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to apply latest version of spring configuration. I want to permit all to the `h2-console` but the application still wants me to authorise.

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .shouldFilterAllDispatcherTypes(false)
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable();

        return http.build();
    }
```

I've tried to even change the url of h2-console but it didn't help. The behaviour is weird because `.requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please re-write the code like this and try again.

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
        .build();
    }
```

Comment: .authorizeRequests() is deprecated in the latest version

Comment: Which spring boot version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To permit different paths you should use:

```
http
    .authorizeHttpRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
    .and()
    ...
```

Keep in Mind: The purpose of requestMatchers() is to specify which requests the spring security configuration will be applied to.

Comment: I can't use antMatchers with authorizeHttpRequests

Comment: I think that I found solution and it look like this:  .requestMatchers(antMatcher("/h2-console/**")).permitAll()